# Непонятная ошибка в Mongoose

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

Есть следующие модели:

```
var BookSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  title: String,
  cover: String,
  author: String,
  about: String,
  genders: [{ type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'Gender' }]
});
var GenderSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: String
});

export default mongoose.model('Gender', GenderSchema);
export default mongoose.model('Book', BookSchema);
```

Думаю, следует отметить, что тут 2 файла обьеденены в 1 для более удобного чтения.

Я пытаюсь создать некоторые данные вот так:

```
Gender.find({}).remove()
  .then(() => {
    Gender.create({
      _id: '561fa3aac09d1fa4egender1',
      name: 'Фантастика'
    }, {
      _id: '561fa3aac09d1fa4egender2',
      name: 'Приключения'
    }, {
      _id: '561fa3aac09d1fa4egender3',
      name: 'Фэнтези'
    })
    .then(() => console.log('finished populating genders'));
  });

Book.find({}).remove()
  .then(() => {
    Book.create({
      title: 'Свободные (СИ)',
      cover: '/assets/images/placeholder.png',
      author: 'Анна Дарк',
      about: 'Криста любила, ждала и верила, но её любовь разбилась о предательство. Адриану не оставили выбора и он решился на отчаянный шаг',
      genders: ['561fa3aac09d1fa4egender1']
    }, {
      title: 'Энигматист (Дело о Божьей Матери)',
      cover: '/assets/images/placeholder.png',
      author: 'Крупенин Артур Борисович',
      about: 'Во второй книге, продолжающей серию детективов о Глебе Стольцеве, главному герою предстоит разгадать загадку, связанную с кражей из московских музеев двух очень похожих между собой икон.',
      genders: ['561fa3aac09d1fa4egender2']
    }, {
      title: 'Город Дождя(СИ)',
      cover: '/assets/images/placeholder.png',
      author: 'Манскова Ольга Витальевна',
      about: 'Не нашел достойного описания, поэтому будет просто текст рандомный =).',
      genders: ['561fa3aac09d1fa4egender3','561fa3aac09d1fa4egender2']
    })
    .then(() => console.log('finished populating books'));
  });
```

И получается ошибка в стиле:

Unhandled rejection ValidationError: CastError: Cast to Array failed for value "561fa3aac09d1fa4egender1" at path "genders"

В комментарии (в коде) выше стрелкой указано куда указывает валидатор. Может, кто сталкивался? Как это исправить? Может, я не так создаю ссылку на другой документ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Надеюсь, поможет тому, кто будет гуглить этот вопрос. Поле _id должно задаваться как строка ХЕКС символов, размером 24. Хекс символы это 0..9, a..f.

Comment: Искал ответ несколько часов, зато теперь знаю больше =)